# Should I avoid checking for two fields in one validation?

Tags: magento2

I want to check both checkout address fields with one validation:

```
validator.addRule(

           'validate-housenumber-both',
           function (value) {
               if ($('[name="street[0]"]').val().match(/\d/) || $('[name="street[1]"]').val().match(/\d/)) {return true;}
                   else {return false;}
           },
           $.mage.__('One of the fields should contain a number')
       );
```

It seems to be working fine, but is there a reason why this should be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

If you are validating frontend input, be 100% certain of ALL possible acceptable values.  What if an address is: "One Commerce Way"?  Could you rule that out as a potential address line 1?

You should be validating addresses with a address validation api, don't you think?  Perhaps the validation API of the shipping service you would use.  The best part about the validation using an API is that they correct potential mistakes, as well as refuse 100% incorrect addresses.